# Replace "existing_time" to "current_sys_time" between XML tags and update in file using Perl. (in format HH:MM:SS)

Tags: regex, perl, shell, perl-module, perl-data-structures

Just want to replace the data between the tags(*) to the current system time and save in the file.

```
#to get in HH:MM:SS

sub tim{
    ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();
    printf ("%02d:%02d:%02d", $hour, $min, $sec);
}
$b = print tim();

use strict;
open(FILE, "+<abc.txt") || die "File not found";
my @lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

my @newlines;
foreach(@lines) {
    $_ =~ s/<daycutoff>.*</<daycutoff>$b</g;
    push(@newlines,$_);
}

open(FILE, "+<abc.txt") || die "File not found";
print FILE @newlines;
close(FILE);
```

I have tried the above, but not correct format

Comment: `$b = print tim();` the `print tim()` statement returns a value of 1 here and its stored in $b. Use sprintf in tim subroutine and remove the print call. Use the assignment in the forloop. Please consider a module if you are doing XML or HTML parsing.

Answer (score -1):

`print` statement returns a value that is stored in the variable $b. Use [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) for string formatting in the subroutine return and then store it in `$b`.

```
sub tim {
  ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();
  sprintf ("%02d:%02d:%02d", $hour, $min, $sec);
}

$b = tim();

foreach(@lines) {
  $_ =~ s/<daycutoff>\K[^<]*</$b</g;
  push(@newlines,$_);
}
```

Please use a XML Parser to parse and manipulate the XML data.
Since I don't know the exact XML data I went ahead with the regex solution. Consider [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple)